# Portforward the ingress hostname deployed in minikube

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, minikube

I have created a pod and service for nginx in a cloud compute VM and with port forward I am able to forward the service to local port, which I am able to access it on browser as http://vm_ip:port.

The result - The page is displayed.

Now I have created an ingress with TLS enabled and mapped the minikube ip with backend dns name for e.g backend.minikube.local. I enabled the TLS using self signed certificate.

I tested the response using curl in VM and I get the result for https (output of result below)

```
#curl --cacert tls.crt https://backend.minikube.local
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
html { color-scheme: light dark; }
body { width: 35em; margin: 0 auto;
font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, how can I view the same from browser from my desktop? I tried to port forward ingress but it fails -

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 ingress/nginx 8080:80
```

error: cannot attach to *v1.Ingress: selector for *v1.Ingress not implemented

Do port-forward only works for pods, service and deployment? not for reverse-proxy?

Please share the solution or insight if anyone able to make it work on browswer.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to use the minikube ip instead of `0.0.0.0`? Because on the curl command you use `https://backend.minikube.local`.

Comment: @Felipe Yes I tried but I get the following error -                                              `#kubectl port-forward --address 192.168.59.2 svc/nginx 8080:80
Unable to listen on port 8080: Listeners failed to create with the following errors: [unable to create listener: Error listen tcp4 192.168.59.2:8080: bind: cannot assign requested address]
error: unable to listen on any of the requested ports: [{8080 80}]`

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56442102/2096986

Comment: @VinuPillai Were you able to solve this issue? Also, how you mapped minikube ip with backend dns in ingress? I'm unable to do that

Answer (score 1):

You have an Nginx service running inside [Minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/) and accessible via an [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/), and you want to access this service from your desktop browser
Direct `kubectl port-forward` to an Ingress resource is not supported, which is why you are encountering errors.

The official documentation for [Minikube Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/) should help. But, since you cannot directly port-forward to an Ingress, the workaround is to port-forward to the underlying service that the Ingress routes traffic to. Find out the name of the service that your Ingress routes to. That is usually defined in the Ingress resource.

Use [`kubectl port-forward`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/port-forward-access-application-cluster/) to forward a local port to the service's port. If your service is named `nginx-service` and you want to use port 8080 on your local machine, the command will be:

```bash
kubectl port-forward svc/nginx-service 8080:80 --address 0.0.0.0
```

That would forward your local port `8080` to the service's port `80`.

Modify your `hosts` file (`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` or `/etc/hosts`) to map the domain used in your Ingress (`backend.minikube.local`) to `127.0.0.1` (localhost). That step is essential for your browser to route the domain to your local machine where the port-forward is listening. Add the following line:

```
127.0.0.1 backend.minikube.local
```

Navigate to `https://backend.minikube.local:8080` in your browser. You should see the Nginx welcome page.

Since your Ingress is configured with TLS using a self-signed certificate, your browser will likely show a security warning. You can proceed with the warning for testing purposes. For production, make sure to use a properly signed certificate.